# HWIOAuthBundle - SSL certificate on Windows

Tags: php, windows, symfony, curl, ssl

I am developing an application with Symfony 2 on a local server running Windows but finding a problem with Curl, namely:

```
SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Would seem to be a common problem for this OS but there is a definitive solution to solve it?

Bearing in mind that deploy the application will be done on a server installed with Linux.

Comment: Have you tried: curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

Comment: No, in which part of the application I put this?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling peer verification is not a good solution.

PHP's curl extension can load a list of verified certificate authorities.

Download http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem from the writer of curl and add this to your php.ini

```
curl.cainfo="c:\php\cacert.pem"
```